# Navigation links not aligning properly after adding a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I recently added a dropdown for one of my navigation links that were in the middle, but for some reason, after adding the dropdown, the navigation links before the dropdown all got pushed to the right.  I did want the navigation to float right, but now all the links before the dropdown nav link has all been pushed to the right.  For context, I also have a javascript and some code to make my site responsive, hamburger icon (not sure if that would be the issue or if the dropdown css has an issue that I can't figure out).  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
        <nav class = "topnav" id = "myTopnav">
            <div class = "floatnav">
                <a href="index.html">Heading 1</a>
                <div class = "dropdown">
                    <button class = "dropbtn">Heading 2</button>
                    <div class = "dropdown-content">
                        <a href = "lostark.html">Subheading</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="support.html">Heading 3</a>
                <a href="about.html">Heading 4</a>
            </div>
            <a href = "javascript:void(0);" class = "icon" onclick = "myFunction()">
                <i class = "fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </nav>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
.floatnav {
    float: right;
}

/* Navbar container */
.floatnav a {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 14px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.floatnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    color: black;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

My navigation bar now shows as the follows:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWJKG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWJKG.png)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: How is this question different from [your last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476467/my-navigation-links-are-not-aligning-properly-on-the-right)?

Comment: Hi! My last question was related to the navigation link that had the dropdown menu being put all the way to the right hand side, but after having that solved, I then ran into this original issue that was described above.